# in QT C++, QMdiSubWindow opens multiple windows

Tags: c++, qt

Well guys I'm sorry but I've been looking at some of the documentation on QT but I still can't make it work, the thing that I want is, well I have and Mdi Area which has a button to add sub window, it's a phonebook and when I click on the button to add a subwindow well it does but if I click it 5 times it will open 5 of the same window and I want to make it open only one no matter how much you click it.

Here's a picture, when I click on that button circled in red it will open that window in the middle. I've tried setting it as active window and using a couple more stuff but nothing has worked yet, any help is greatly appreciated.

[link to the picture on imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykVuv.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple. Don't create another window if it already has been created.

In the header file:

```
QMdiSubWindow* subwindow;
```

In the constructor:

```
subwindow = 0;
```

In the button's onclick slot:

```
if (!subwindow) {
  subwindow = ui->mdi_area->addSubWindow(widget);
}
subwindow->show();
subwindow->setFocus();
```

By default a subwindow is not deleted when it's closed, so you can use the same object again.

Answer (score 0):

you could inspect the subWindowList before opening:

```
  bool is_open = false;
  foreach(QMdiSubWindow *subw, ui->mdi_area->subWindowList())
    if (qobject_cast<YouWindowClass>(subw) != nullptr) is_open = true;
```